# How to send on server multiple data using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following situation: a user can define a questionnaire by adding elements on the document definition template. It may add simple questions or questions with multiple selection or single selection. The following picture is the output.[image]

The question is how i am able to send user defined data on server using ajax(a document may have multiple check boxes and multiple radio buttons).What I've tried to far is to get every element and store it into an array, but i am stuck on how to send it on server.

```
$('#saveDocDef').click(function(){

        //get the document definition name
        var docName = $('#docName').val();
        if(docName == ""){
            alert("You need to choose a name for the document");
            return;
        }
        //get the selected status
        var docStatus = $('#selectStatus').val();
        if(docStatus == ''){
            alert("You need to select a valid status for the document");
            return;
        }

        //create a form to serialize the defined elements
        //make sure that the form doesn't exist
        $('#frmSubmit').remove();
        //append it to body
        $('body').append('<form id="frmSubmit" action=""></form>');
        //all elements are hidden
        //append the name and the status of the document definition
        $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="name"  value="'+ docName +'">');
        $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="status"  value="'+ docStatus +'">');

        /*************************QUESTION****************************/
        //get all questions content
        var questionText = $('.doc-def-quest-text');
        $(questionText).each(function(index){
            $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ questionText['index']+'" name="questionContent" value="'+ questionText.eq(index).val() +'">');

        });

        /**************************CHECK BOX*************************/

        //get all checkboxes elements content
        var ckbElements = $('.ckbElem');
        //create new checkbox definition for each element   
        $(ckbElements).each(function(index){
            var ckbQuest = $(ckbElements[index]).find('.ckbQuestionText').val();                
            $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ ckbElements['index']+'" name="question" value="'+ ckbQuest +'">');
            var predefinedAnswers = $(ckbElements[index]).find('.ckbOptions')[0];
            $(predefinedAnswers).each(function(i){
                $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ predefinedAnswers['i']+'" name="options" value="'+predefinedAnswers.options[i].text +'">');
            });
        });

        /**************************RADIO***************************/
        //get all radio elements content
        var radioElements = $('.radioElem');
        //create new radio definition for each element
        $(radioElements).each(function(index){
            var radioQuest =  $(radioElements[index]).find('.radioQuestionText').val();
            $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ radioElements['index']+'" name="question" value="'+ radioQuest +'">');
            var predefinedAnswers = $(radioElements[index]).find('.radioOptions')[0];
            $(predefinedAnswers).each(function(i){
                $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ predefinedAnswers['i']+'" name="options" value="'+predefinedAnswers.options[i].text +'">');
            });
        }); 

        var result = $('form').serialize();
        $( "#results" ).text( result );

        $.ajax({
            url :"/eMuse/admin/saveDocument",
            dataType: 'json',
            accepts :{
                xml : 'text/xml',
                text: 'text/plain'
            },
            data : {request : result},
            success : function(response){
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Make a query string and pass to the server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the form elements with multiple selections give the same form name:
for example:

```
<input type="checkout" name="language[]" value="english">
<input type="checkout" name="french[]" value="english">
```

( the [] will send the information in an array )

you can use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and send it as a post or get method.

```
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: This should go as a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: i cannot comment. i do not have the reputation for tat.,

Comment: @callback I agree with you in the sense it is one lined. Aryeh should expand this answer so that it can actually show how to do it with seralize AND the ajax. I would recommend just showing an ajax POST with serialize. This will allow people to upvote your answer so in the future you can comment.

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Any input regarding my answer would be appropriated since i'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = { 'docName' : docName , 'docStatus' : docStatus ,'questionText' :questionText ,'answers' :answers };
$.ajax({

    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```